# How to read xml response generated by HTTP POST Interface

Tags: asp.net, xml, httpwebrequest

I generate request to a certain API which is mentioned here for sending an sms http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/evolution.sms.postapi

The request generates an XML response as follow

```
 <rsp stat="ok">

 <success msg="accepted" transactionid="2e47fe224d25559a696a7bdddec1828b" messageid="cf0d21f067e5b386a2e042134687eb5c"/>

  </rsp>
```

I want to read if rsp stat in response is ok or fail how can i do it .

These are the first two lines how can i get particular xml tag out of response stream

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

 Stream content = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: i think you can use regular expression to parse particular data from response xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to parse the XML. For example,

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(content))
{
   var doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd()); 
   // you may want to compare case in-sensitive
   if (doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["stat"].Value == "ok") 
   {
       // success
   }
}
```

*(There is also `Load` method that would load from stream directly but I am not sure if it expects xml declaration at the beginning or not)*

Yet another alternative is using `XmlReader` in case response could be lengthy and you wants to parse the initial bits as soon as its available.

Answer (score 0):

try to read with `XmlTextReader` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)